# JPA update the forigen key of Entity got error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have 2 tables:

```
1- DEPARTMENT_TABLE(ID PK, NAME);
2- EMPLOYEE_TABLE (ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID FK);
```

The Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT_TABLE")
public class Department {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   private String name;

   ............. set/get methods ................

}

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE_TABLE")
public class Employee {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", nullable=false, unique=false)
   private Department department;


   ............. set/get methods ................

}
```

In the jsf page:

```
<p:datatable .... value ="#{empMB.allEmployees}" var="emp">
  .....
   <h:selectonemenu .. value="emp.department.id" ....>
```

.......

And the JPA DAO use the Hiberate framework.

```
public class JPA_DAO{

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="silenceUnit")
protected EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

protected EntityManager entityManager;

private UserTransaction transaction;
  .....................................
   public void updateEmplyee(Employee employee){
       transaction.begin();
       entityManager.joinTransaction();
       entityManager.merge(employee);
       transaction.commit();
     }
.............................
}
```

in the front-end i use the promefaces to display all employees with the department, and I can change the department of employee through select the department from drop-down-list which contains all departments.

but when i change the department id from the drop-down-list and try to marge, i get the error :

```
  identifier of an instance of Department was altered from 2 to 1
```

but if try to update the employee without select the department from the drop-down-list (manually) it's working fine.

```
Department dep = findDepartment(10);
employee.setDepartment(dep);
jpaDao.updateEmployee(employee);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change departement id" ? You should load the newly selected departement and set it to employee.

Comment: what are you passing in dropdown

Comment: The list contains department id as value and department as label